# Nested "for" loops in R

Tags: r

I'm an R novice with what I hope is a simple question.  I've got a couple of nested loops I'm running and can't seem to get the output that I'm expecting.

I want to keep track of the balance in the internal loop.  Each iteration represents 1 year.  At the end of 15 years, I want to write the final balance to InvTotal for each of 4 simulations.

My final output should be 3 vectors (1 for each investment) of length 4, showing the final cumulative value for each investment at the end of 4 simulations.

My code is below.  Any assistance you could provide would be a huge help.

Thank you!

```
Investment1_Balance <- 10000
Investment2_Balance <- 10000
Investment3_Balance <- 10000

Inv1Returns <- c(0, 1000, -500, 500)
Inv2Returns <- c(0, -9000, 30000, 10000)
Inv3Returns <- c(0, 4000, -1000, -2000)

Inv1Outcome = NULL
Inv2Outcome = NULL
Inv3Outcome = NULL

Inv1Total = NULL
Inv2Total = NULL
Inv3Total = NULL

random = NULL

for (j in 1:4)


{

for (i in 1:15 ) 


{
  random[i] = runif(1, 0, 1)

  Inv1Outcome[i] = if (random[i] <= .25){Investment1_Balance + Inv1Returns[1]} 
  else if (random[i] > .25 & random[i] <= .50){Investment1_Balance + Inv1Returns[2]}
  else if (random[i] > .50 & random[i] <= .75){Investment1_Balance + Inv1Returns[3]}
  else {Investment1_Balance + Inv1Returns[4]}

  Inv2Outcome[i] = if (random[i] <= .20){Investment2_Balance + Inv2Returns[1]} 
  else if (random[i] > .20 & random[i] <= .30){Investment2_Balance + Inv2Returns[2]}
  else if (random[i] > .30 & random[i] <= .70){Investment2_Balance + Inv2Returns[3]}
  else ({Investment2_Balance + Inv2Returns[4]})

  Inv3Outcome[i] = if (random[i] <= .50){Investment3_Balance + Inv3Returns[1]} 
  else if (random[i] > .50 & random[i] <= .70){Investment3_Balance + Inv3Returns[2]}
  else if (random[i] > .70 & random[i] <= .90){Investment3_Balance + Inv3Returns[3]}
  else ({Investment3_Balance + Inv3Returns[4]})

  Investment1_Balance[i] =+ Inv1Outcome[i]
  Investment2_Balance[i] =+ Inv2Outcome[i]
  Investment3_Balance[i] =+ Inv3Outcome[i]

}

Inv1Total[j] = Investment1_Balance[15]

Inv2Total[j] = Investment2_Balance[15]

Inv3Total[j] = Investment3_Balance[15]

}

Inv1Total
Inv2Total
Inv3Total
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stackoverflow! There are a couple of points that you should consider while trying to figure out why your code isn't working as expected:

1. **"Start small"** : In your case here, I would start with one investment, maybe even with one simulation. This would verify if the logic of the calculation is fine, without distracting myself with other numbers.
2. **"Seeing is believing"** : Try to print intermediate results, so you can trace the calculation bugs.

Applying the previous, a first debugging would would look something like:

```
Investment1_Balance <- 10000
Inv1Returns <- c(0, 1000, -500, 500)
Inv1Outcome = NULL
Inv1Total = NULL

random = NULL

for (j in 1:4) { # Loop over simulations 

  cat("\n\n\nSimulation  ", j, ": Investment balance:" , Investment1_Balance) 

  for (i in 1:15) { # Loop over years

    random[i] = runif(1, 0, 1) 

    Inv1Outcome[i] = if (random[i] <= .25){Investment1_Balance + Inv1Returns[1]} 
    else if (random[i] > .25 & random[i] <= .50){Investment1_Balance + Inv1Returns[2]}
    else if (random[i] > .50 & random[i] <= .75){Investment1_Balance +     Inv1Returns[3]}
    else {Investment1_Balance + Inv1Returns[4]}

    Investment1_Balance[i] =+ Inv1Outcome[i]    

    cat("\n   Year: ", i, "- Outcome:", Inv1Outcome[i], "- Final balance: " , Investment1_Balance[i])

  }

  Inv1Total[j] = Investment1_Balance[15]
}

Inv1Total
```

.

**You can see a couple of problems with the numbers printed :**

1. The outcome is always the same as the balance. This suggests that there might be a problem with the addition.

Let's try to debug that:

```
> x = 10
> x =+ 2
> x
[1] 2
```

Apparently, the `=+` isn't working as expected. So we have to correct that :     `Investment1_Balance[i+1] = Investment1_Balance[i] + Inv1Outcome[i]`

.

2. When printing the initial investment balance for each simulation, we can see that the first simulation is fine `(Simulation   1 : Investment balance: 10000)`. But for the other simulations we get `(Simulation   2 : Investment balance: 10000 9500 10000 10000 10500 11000 9500 11000 10000 10500 10500 10000 10000 11000 11000)`.

This suggests a problem with the initialization. Each simulation takes the output of the previous and starts with it. The logic of that is not quite correct. The simple solution would be resetting `Investment1_Balance <- 10000` at the beginning of each simulation. It would even make sense in this case to reset all the Balance and Outcome variables.

.

**Here is the new code after debugging :**

```
Inv1Returns <- c(0, 1000, -500, 500)

random = NULL
Inv1Total = NULL


for (j in 1:4) { # Loop over simulations 

  Investment1_Balance <- 10000
  Inv1Outcome = NULL

  cat("\n\n\nSimulation  ", j, ": Investment balance:" , Investment1_Balance)

  for (i in 1:15) { # Loop over years

    random[i] = runif(1, 0, 1) 

Inv1Outcome[i] = if (random[i] <= .25){Investment1_Balance + Inv1Returns[1]} 
    else if (random[i] > .25 & random[i] <= .50){Investment1_Balance + Inv1Returns[2]}
    else if (random[i] > .50 & random[i] <= .75){Investment1_Balance + Inv1Returns[3]}
    else {Investment1_Balance + Inv1Returns[4]}

    Investment1_Balance[i+1] = Investment1_Balance[i] + Inv1Outcome[i]

    cat("\n   Year: ", i, "- Outcome:", Inv1Outcome[i], "- Final balance: " , Investment1_Balance[i])

  }

  Inv1Total[j] = Investment1_Balance[15]
}

Inv1Total
```

Check if the output is now correct. If so, you can go ahead and add Inv2 and Inv3 as well.

Comment: This was a huge help.  Thanks, Deena!